# How to limit concurrent user session in rails app that uses devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

**Limiting concurrent user sessions or login:**

For a user I needs to apply limit while login. I want to allow a user user@gmail.com to be able to login from different 5 PCs or browsers only.

**What I used:**

I added two fields to users table called session_limit (to specify user login limits) and session_count( to store currently running sessions for that user).

I added one to session_count when user login and subtract one from session  when user logout or timeout occurs. I checked session_count while logging in and logged out when it reaches session_limit. It worked fine at first.

**What problem I faced:**

When user closes browser without logout session_count remains not deducted  and when user logins next time it says user_session limit reached. Even if there is none logged in.

Please Help.

Comment: you can use websockets to detect when a browser window is closed and decrease the session_count

Comment: This is what I had already think about but, it will be nice if there is any best way to accomplish it from server side.

Comment: what you can do is display to the user a list of their connected devices (you can use HTTP USER AGENT) to figure out which is which. Then prompt them to sign off from one or more.